# How can I have Fun with the Lutefisk Cube?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I recently attempted to convert a spare Horadric Lutefisk Cube I found into lutefisk.

Instead of lutefisk, the cubes produced a fiery death. (I survived the initial explosion, but the fire got me the next turn. Cause of death is listed as "spell mine.")

Are there any other items (e.g. N-dimensional Lathe) which produce Fun instead of lutefisk when placed inside the cube? If so, what kinds of Fun can I obtain through fanatical devotion to the lutefisk god?

Comment: I would upvote this, but I refuse to be the one responsible for spoiling that fantastic reputation score.

Comment: I just wanted to say, I haven't played the game but I have absolutely *no* idea what the hell you're talking about. This game sounds mental.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer the question, no, only Lutefisk cubes have this reaction when put into another Lutefisk cube, anything else will just be skoled into lutefisk.